# How to count how many item in a json array list

Tags: python, count

How can i count how many list inside an array? For example 2 is the answer for this list `['[["Subject","NotContain","test1"],["Text","Equals","test2"]]']`. I had tried to count with `len(dataarray.split()))` but everytime the answer only shows 1 instead of two.

```
    arr = request.POST.getlist('data[]', None)
    print(arr)
    
    //OUTPUT: ['[["Subject","NotContain","test1"],["Text","Equals","test2"]]']


    dataarray = " ".join(str(x) for x in arr)
    print(len(dataarray.split()))

    //OUTPUT: 1
```

Comment: your output is list with a single encapsulated string, no array. You can use .split("],[") if you are only interested in length

Comment: @j1-lee The json array is retrieved from a javascript from front end. Yes you are correct, its a list containing two lists. But how can I know know the length of the list?

Comment: It is NOT a list containing two lists.  It is a list containing one string, which itself happens to be JSON.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not recognize that this is a list containing a single JSON string?  Just decode the JSON:

```
arr = request.POST.getlist('data[]', None)
print(arr)    
//OUTPUT: ['[["Subject","NotContain","test1"],["Text","Equals","test2"]]']

dataarray = json.loads( arr[0] )
print(dataarray)
//OUTPUT: [["Subject","NotContain","test1"],["Text","Equals","test2"]]

print(len(dataarray))
//OUTPUT: 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Im still new to coding especially python and json stuffs. Does it mean i need to decode the json everytime when I retrieve the array from javascript?

Comment: Yes.  JSON is always transmitted as a string.  That's the whole point -- to represent complex structures as a single string.  The Javascript side ENCODES it, and you as the consumer have to DECODE it.

Comment: Thanks, look like I should read more about JSON and try to understand the theory before dive in coding haha